# Heroku Deployment Issue Sharetribe

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, sharetribe

Unable to Fix the Issue

Error Logs :- `Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_67f35ffd23ead4c.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist`

I have no idea what the hell all the mystery table errors mean or how I would even resolve them??

```
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135283+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:175:in `block (4 levels) in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135273+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `work_off'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135284+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135287+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135273+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `times'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135288+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135288+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135289+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135293+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `loop'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135294+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `block in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135295+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135295+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135296+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135297+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135297+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135298+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135298+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:171:in `start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135300+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135299+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135300+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135301+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135301+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135302+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135302+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135303+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135304+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135304+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135305+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135305+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135306+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135306+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135307+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135307+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135308+00:00 app[worker.1]: Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_67f35ffd23ead4c.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135907+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135908+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135909+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135909+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135911+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135910+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `block in execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135912+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135912+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135913+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135914+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135914+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:316:in `execute_and_free'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135915+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:463:in `columns'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135915+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:43:in `columns'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135916+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:93:in `columns'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135917+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:98:in `columns_hash'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135927+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:109:in `block in sanitize_sql_hash_for_assignment'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135928+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:108:in `each'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135929+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:108:in `map'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135929+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:108:in `sanitize_sql_hash_for_assignment'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135930+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:40:in `sanitize_sql_for_assignment'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135930+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:332:in `update_all'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135931+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.1.1/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb:111:in `reserve_with_scope_using_optimized_sql'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135932+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.1.1/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb:81:in `reserve_with_scope'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135932+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.1.1/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb:74:in `reserve'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135933+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:310:in `reserve_job'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135933+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:305:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135934+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `block in work_off'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135934+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `times'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135935+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `work_off'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135935+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:175:in `block (4 levels) in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135936+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135936+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135937+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135937+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135938+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135942+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `loop'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135943+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `block in start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135943+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135944+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135944+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135945+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135945+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135946+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135946+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:171:in `start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135947+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135947+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135948+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135948+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135949+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135949+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135958+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135959+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135959+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135960+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135960+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135961+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135964+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135965+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135965+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135966+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135968+00:00 app[worker.1]: Tasks: TOP => jobs:work
2016-12-19T09:33:13.135990+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2016-12-19T09:33:13.143224+00:00 app[worker.1]: ** [NewRelic][12/19/16 09:33:13 +0000 b3b82f50-3828-40a0-93a7-b76adb239a35 (4)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
2016-12-19T09:33:13.147813+00:00 app[worker.1]: ** [NewRelic][12/19/16 09:33:13 +0000 b3b82f50-3828-40a0-93a7-b76adb239a35 (4)] WARN : Removing #<NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler:0x007fd88af1adc8> from list
2016-12-19T09:33:13.147972+00:00 app[worker.1]: ** [NewRelic][12/19/16 09:33:13 +0000 b3b82f50-3828-40a0-93a7-b76adb239a35 (4)] WARN : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'heroku_67f35ffd23ead4c.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `delayed_jobs`
2016-12-19T09:33:13.621753+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-19T09:33:13.634941+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed


When I try to run heroku db:migrate I get this:

/app/.bash_profile: line 1: /app/.bashrc: No such file or directory
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.1.236/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/default_source.rb:675: warning: key :disable_mongo is duplicated and overwritten on line 987
Migrating to AddDescriptionToItem (20090219094209)
== 20090219094209 AddDescriptionToItem: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:items, :description, :text, {:default=>""})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'description' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `items` ADD `description` text DEFAULT ''/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:407:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20090219094209_add_description_to_item.rb:3:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1046:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'description' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `items` ADD `description` text DEFAULT ''
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:407:in `add_column'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'description' can't have a default value
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:407:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20090219094209_add_description_to_item.rb:3:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1046:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is reported already in Sharetribe. https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe/issues/2090

You need to run `rake db:schema:load` instead of `rake db:migrate` at the first time installation.